# How to show and hide partial view on button click?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to show and hide my partial view when the same button is clicked.
The below code work for showing the partial view. How do I remove the partial view if the user click the same button again?

```html
<div id="myPartialView"></div>
```

```js
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/Home/GetData',
    datatype: "html",
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      $('#myPartialView').empty();
      $('#myPartialView').html(result)
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
      alert('error - ' + errorMessage);
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Toggle 'hidden' attribute on that element. I assume you only want to fetch data once and then keep it stored in the element until clicked again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm caching `myPartialView` to a variable so we just have to look for it once.

EDIT:

Changed the code to test for `:empty`, so it should work even in the initial state.

```js
$('#myBtn').click(function () {
    var $myPartialView = $('#myPartialView');
    if ($myPartialView.is(':empty')) {
      $.ajax({
          url: '/Home/GetData',
          datatype: "html",
          type: "GET",
          cache: false,
          success: function (result) {
              $myPartialView.html(result);
          },
          error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
              alert('error - ' + errorMessage);
          }
      });
    }
    else {
      $myPartialView.empty();
    }
    
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The first time the button is clicked, nothing happens. Every click afterward would hide or show the partial view

Comment: That's because it's initial state is `visible` but it's empty. You can set it's style to `style="display: none"`

Comment: Try the new version. It checks for `:empty`, so it should work even in the initial state.